# How stop local notification sound after cancel local notification

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

In my application I scheduled local notification with custom sound. After I cancel it from code the sound continue playing. How can I stop it?

```
-(void)cancelNotification{
    if(localNotification){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can you cancel it ..because notification sound play whenever your notification brings .. so please put code of how you cancel notif ?

Comment: I stop local notification. So obviously behaviour is that sound should stop playing.

Comment: stop means on/off notification ?? and make sure that you canceled notification is current(playing sound) notif.. ??

Comment: I provide my question with code. I have cancel local notification, I have not change settings on/off

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code like below, hope this works for you. I am adding this just for a try.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification

{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `didRecieveRemoteNotification` set your application icon badge number. It will do the trick.

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

    {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when initially testing with an iPhone 4.

The problem *appears* to have gone away as of iOS 8 and now Local Notification Sounds stop when canceled after transitioning to the App.

**iPhone4 [ iOS - 7.1.2 ]** - Local Notification sound keeps playing in App no matter what 
**iPhone6 [ iOS - 8.1.1 ]** - Local Notification sound stop when canceled programmatically

From what I can infer, it appears a fix exists somewhere in iOS 8.x
*(Alas I didn't manage to find any documentation or release notes on the matter.)*

**The Problem becomes a non-issue for apps focusing on iOS 8**
*(provided you cancel the Local Notification coming in)*

I used this same answer [for a Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27238910/3200482)